# Need a way to add one property to the msi properties table in setup project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I've been using Orca to manually add property "REINSTALLMODE" value "amus" into the msi property table every time I build it.

I'm sick of this. I looked into Wix but so far I don't think its worth the hassle to learn it/switch to it just yet, even though it will solve this problem. Is there a way I can automatically insert this one property into the msi after the build is complete? Preferably, it will use only vanilla visual studio 2010 and not depend on third party programs or system environment variables.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Isaac

Comment: Note that REINSTALLMODE=amus can do really bad things if you include any shared files in your installer. By replacing **all** versions, it will downgrade anything out there. If REINSTALLMODE=emus works for you, I would strongly suggest it instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a vbscript

change an existing property

```
set o_installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
set o_database = o_Installer.OpenDatabase("path_to_your_msi", 1)
s_SQL = "SELECT Property, Value FROM Property Where Property = 'ReinstallMode'"
Set o_MSIView = o_DataBase.OpenView(s_SQL)
o_MSIView.Execute
Set o_MSIRecord = o_MSIView.Fetch
o_MSIRecord.StringData(2) = "amus"
o_MSIView.Modify 2, o_MSIRecord
o_DataBase.Commit
```

add an new property

```
set o_installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
set o_database = o_Installer.OpenDatabase("path_to_your_msi", 1)
s_SQL = "INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) Values( 'ReinstallMode', 'amus')"
Set o_MSIView = o_DataBase.OpenView( s_SQL)
o_MSIView.Execute
o_DataBase.Commit
```

Comment: The property is called REINSTALLMODE not ReinstallMode.  Also you probably need to do an UPDATE not an INSERT.

Comment: This quick hack works great. I'll figure out how to make it post build somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to include the version number in the application's install folder.
Set Application folder's default location to something like:
[ProgramFilesFolder]\[ProductName]\[ProductVersion]
Also set the Setup project's 'RemovePreviousVersions' property to true.
This should delete the old version's folder and create a fresh folder for the new version.
Remember to change the Setup project's version property every time you do a new release.

Comment: This worked perfectly; it deleted the old DLL of the wrong version and it also installed the correct ones!  Hail Gustav!!

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score 1):

My honest thoughts?  You are starting down the road of "VDPROJ is fine except I also need it to do [x]."  You'll find a way to hack it and then you'll repeat.  Before you know it you'll have a frankenstein solution that is doing all kinds of wierd things to your MSI because the tool doesn't expose it or worse implements it wrong.  I really suggest going to InstallShield 2010LE/Pro or WiX.

However, if all you want to do is change REINSTALLMODE from omus to amus,  I reccomend using Orca to create a transform one time and then in a post build step apply the transform to your built MSI.

```
cscript WiUseXfm.vbs [path to original database][path to transform file][options]
```

[Apply a Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367577%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, when looking at Wix I thought it was inevitable that we'd have to move to it... someday.. when I feel like learning something new.

Comment: This program is going to be installed on < 20 computers though, and actually having an msi file is already a huge step up from what we're replacing (foxpro).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I went with the other guys though because I couldn't find that wiusexfm file anywhere. Its supposedly in this sdk but the sdk is 2.5 gigs and I couldn't wait. If we need more complex scripts than just this I'll use transforms. If they get worse I'll go to wix. Thanks for your thoughts today! -Isaac

Comment: You can always just call the msi as msiexec /i foo.msi REINSTALLMODE=amus if you are only doing 20 machines.  That or build your files with proper version numbers so you don't need to override the default omus behavior.

Comment: Christopher is this still available? I can't find it in my MicrosoftSDK's and I have tried MsiTran but getting the error 110 and there dosen seem to be much help on it. Thanks

Comment: Nat, you use WiX so take a look at the tool called Torch.