# Add Visual Studio 2010 custom property for .msi installer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, x86-64

How do I add a custom property in visual studio 2010 for an .msi generated at build time.
The .msi file should have a property named "BUILDARCHITECTURE". If it's not difficult this property should be automatically changed to x64 or x86 when I change the build platform. 
If this is not possible I can just hardcode it to x86 ( it will be deployed on 32 bit machines ).

In Orca I can just go to the Property Table then just right click and add row and it works. 
But I need to add it automatically at build time in VS2010.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a post-build step, and I'd start with WiRunSql.vbs from the Windows Kit SDK. It's a script that takes a SQL statement to update an MSI file. You want a SQL something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`.`Property`, `Property`.`Value`) VALUES ('BUILDARCITECTURE', 'whatever')
```

However why do you need it there? An MSI knows its architecture with the VersionNT64 property, so inside the MSI you just use that, or pass it to your custom actions or whatever.

From outside the MSI you can get the architecture from the summary info stream template property, as in this dumb vbscript:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim installer
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer") 
Dim sumInfo  : Set sumInfo = installer.SummaryInformation("another.msi", 0)
dim someproperty
someproperty = suminfo.Property(7)

msgbox someproperty
set suminfo = Nothing 
set installer=nothing
```

Comment: Did you intend to use code snippets instead of code blocks ?

Comment: I wanted something to preserve the peck marks, if code blocks do that, cool.

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I've gone with a similar approach like Phil's.
Meaning I added a post build event :

```
set msiFile=$(OutDir)\setup.msi

if "$(Configuration)" == "Release" (
wscript $(SolutionDir)\..\Build\AddCustomProperty.vbs %msiFile%
```

VBS Script :

```
set o_installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
set o_database = o_Installer.OpenDatabase("path_to_your_msi", 1)
s_SQL = "INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) Values( '<CustomProperty>', '<custom_property_value>')"
Set o_MSIView = o_DataBase.OpenView( s_SQL)
o_MSIView.Execute
o_DataBase.Commit
```

The script was taken from : [Need a way to add one property to the msi properties table in setup project in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212724/need-a-way-to-add-one-property-to-the-msi-properties-table-in-setup-project-in-v)